# why stripe.Charge.list retrieves up to only 100 charges?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I use the following code to retrieve all the charges:

`charges=stripe.Charge.list(limit=10000)`

But the code retrieves only up to 100 charges. Why?

Comment: It's in the documentation, all the listing APIs limit you to retrieving 100 items at a time. You need to use pagination.

Comment: What is pagination? I need to retrieve the list of all charges in python. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list)

> `limit` *optional*
> A limit on the number of objects to be returned. Limit can range between 1 and 100, and the default is 10.

If you specify a limit more than 100, it caps it at 100.

You need to call it repeatedly to get the next group. Use the `starting_after` option for subsequent calls:

> A cursor for use in pagination. `starting_after` is an object ID that defines your place in the list. For instance, if you make a list request and receive 100 objects, ending with `obj_foo`, your subsequent call can include `starting_after=obj_foo` in order to fetch the next page of the list.

Comment: adding on, Stripe libraries support auto-pagination : https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto